# Check if object is of type String

Tags: java, string, variables

I need to write a new method that checks if certain values are of the type String or not.

I have two objects and I want to be able to check if these two objects are strings, if they are to then return true, and false otherwise.

I did start off with the following method:

```
public boolean stringTest()
{  
    boolean aString;
}
```

But could not get anything to work after that, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These two variables already are `String`'s. If you have an `Object` variable you can check, whether it is a `String` class instance via `myObj instanceof String`

Comment: I do apologise, I've misread the question. It is indeed an object that I am checking!

Comment: what do you mean by string? do you mean don't have numerical characters in it(and ofcourse that is not the definition of string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `instanceof`  and rewrite your method

```
public boolean stringTest(Object any)
{  
   return any instanceof String;

}
```

then

```
stringTest(townName); // true
stringTest(new Integer()); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `instanceof`:

```
public boolean isString(Object o) {
    return o instanceof String;
}
```